# C++/opencv: how to delete specific path pixels in efficient way

Tags: c++, opencv

given an Mat with 4*4 element like this:

`[1,2,3,4
 5,6,7,8
 9,10,11,12
 13,14,15,16
]`

I want to delete specific pixel every row, that means delete [0,0] [1,1] [2,0]
 [3,1] position element ,to become

`[2,3,4
 5,7,8
 10,11,12
 13,15,16
]`

Note: the size of Mat is changed.
Question: Is there a efficient way to do these operation?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the only viable option is to copy the matrix pixel-by-pixel with omitting the unwanted pixels as they are scattered around the source matrix in different rows and columns, so there's no one-liner for that.

```
std::vector<int> indices = { 0, 1, 0, 1 };
cv::Mat dest_mat(source_mat.rows, source_mat.cols - 1, source_mat.type());
int idx = 0;
int dest_col = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < source_mat.rows; ++i)
{
    int* dest_row = dest_mat.ptr<int>(i);
    const int* source_row = source_mat.ptr<int>(i);
    dest_col = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < source_mat.cols; ++j)
    {
        if (j != indices[idx])
        {
            dest_row[dest_col] = source_row[j];
            ++dest_col;
        }
        else
            ++idx;
    }
}
```

The above code assumes that each row contains one unwanted pixel because that's how I understood your task. You may want to adjust `ptr<>()` so that its type fits the one you actually use.